# Return Max value + name from a 2 dimensional List C#

Tags: c#

I have created a 2-dimensional list and want to return the maximum value, the minimum value, and the names that have the same index as these values.

This is what i did.

```
class Info
{
    private string stad;
    private double temperatur;

    public string Stad
    {
        get { return stad; }
        set { stad = value; }
    }

    public double Temperatur
    {
        get { return temperatur; }
        set { temperatur = value; }
    }
}

    static double SearchMax(List<Info> list)
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Tomt Lista");
        }
        double Temperatur = double.MinValue;
        foreach (Info temperatur in list)
        {
            if (temperatur.Temperatur > Temperatur)
            {
                Temperatur = temperatur.Temperatur;
            }        
        }
        return Temperatur;
    }

    static double SearchMin(List<Info> list)
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Tomt Lista");
        }
        double Tempertatur = double.MaxValue;
        foreach (Info temperatur in list)
        {
            if (temperatur.Temperatur < Tempertatur)
            {
                Tempertatur = temperatur.Temperatur;
            }
        }
        return Tempertatur;
    }
```

But what I get in return is only the maximum and minimum values, not the name of the city that the temperature is in.

Can anyone tell me or show me how to return both?

Thank you for all the help you provide but it just put me back to where I was before posting this up here. What I want is for the program to return both the city and the temperature in the city
i.e "Warmest city is Oslo and it's 20 °C warm"
and not "Warmest city is consoleaplication.info"

edit:2
Thank you for all yours help and especialy Alex ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static TempratureInfo FindHighestTemprature(IList<TempratureInfo> tempratures)
{
    if(tempratures.Count == 0)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("tempratures");

    return tempratures.OrderByDescending(t => t.Temprature)
                      .First();
}

private static TempratureInfo FindLowestTemprature(IList<TempratureInfo> tempratures)
{
    if (tempratures.Count == 0)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("tempratures");

    return tempratures.OrderBy(t => t.Temprature)
                      .First();
}
```

You can ammend your `Info` class to override `ToString` which will return the formatted string when you call either of the functions above when a string is expected, argument pass, variable assignment etc.

```
internal class TempratureInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Temprature { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Temprature in {0} is currently {1}", Name, Temprature);
    }
}
```

Sample implementation:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TempratureInfo> unitedKingdomTempratures = new List<TempratureInfo>()
            {
                {new TempratureInfo() { Name = "Wales", Temprature = 10.0}},
                {new TempratureInfo() { Name = "England", Temprature = 55.0}},
                {new TempratureInfo() { Name = "Scotland", Temprature = 22.0}},
                {new TempratureInfo() { Name = "Northen Ireland", Temprature = 4.0}}
            };

        Console.WriteLine("Hottest: " + FindHighestTemprature(unitedKingdomTempratures).Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Coldest: " + FindLowestTemprature(unitedKingdomTempratures).Name);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `Console.WriteLine(FindHighestTemprature(unitedKingdomTempratures));` try `Console.WriteLine(FindHighestTemprature(unitedKingdomTempratures).Name);`

Comment: @VoDanh Updated the post for you :)

Comment: the only problem is that when there are 2 cities with the same temperatur it will only return the first city though but still its a great help i really apreciate it ^_^

Answer (score 2):

A very compact but inefficient LINQ solution:

```
static Info SearchMin(List<Info> list)
{
     return data.OrderBy(i => i.Temperatur).First();
}
```

But you may want to adapt your own code:

```
static Info SearchMin(List<Info> list)
{
    if (list.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Tomt Lista");
    }
    double Tempertatur = double.MaxValue;
    Info result = null;

    foreach (Info temperatur in list)
    {
        if (temperatur.Temperatur < Tempertatur)
        {
            Tempertatur = temperatur.Temperatur;
            result = temperatur;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

As you can see the main point is to return an `Info` and not a `double`.

Comment: hmm but when it return it return "consoleaplication.info" it doesnt return the maximun value and the name of the city. now im just running around in a circle but thanx anyway for trying to help

Comment: It returns an Info object. When you print that it will return its Name. Print `r.Temperatur` and `r.Stad` separately.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [MaxBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs?r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c) and [MinBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs?r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c) methods from MoreLinq to do this.

```
public static partial class MoreEnumerable
{
    public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
    {
        return source.MaxBy(selector, Comparer<TKey>.Default);
    }

    public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> selector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> sourceIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!sourceIterator.MoveNext())
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence was empty");
            }
            TSource max = sourceIterator.Current;
            TKey maxKey = selector(max);
            while (sourceIterator.MoveNext())
            {
                TSource candidate = sourceIterator.Current;
                TKey candidateProjected = selector(candidate);
                if (comparer.Compare(candidateProjected, maxKey) > 0)
                {
                    max = candidate;
                    maxKey = candidateProjected;
                }
            }
            return max;
        }
    }
    public static TSource MinBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
    {
        return source.MinBy(selector, Comparer<TKey>.Default);
    }

    public static TSource MinBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> selector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> sourceIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!sourceIterator.MoveNext())
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence was empty");
            }
            TSource min = sourceIterator.Current;
            TKey minKey = selector(min);
            while (sourceIterator.MoveNext())
            {
                TSource candidate = sourceIterator.Current;
                TKey candidateProjected = selector(candidate);
                if (comparer.Compare(candidateProjected, minKey) < 0)
                {
                    min = candidate;
                    minKey = candidateProjected;
                }
            }
            return min;
        }
    }
}
```

(Edited to remove comments and null checking of arguments.)

Once you have that it's pretty trivial:

```
Info maxInfo = list.MaxBy(item => item.Temperatur);
Info minInfo = list.MinBy(item => item.Temperatur);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure this can be tweaked a little bit to make it shorter:

```
var maxtemp = list.Max(x => x.Temperatur);
var maxstad = list.First(x => x.Temperatur == maxtemp).Stad;

var mintemp = list.Min(x => x.Temperatur);
var minstad = list.First(x => x.Temperatur == mintemp).Stad;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just order by the `Temperatur` and take the first one.

This may be slow on BIG lists

```
    static Info SearchMax(List<Info> list)
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Tomt Lista");
        }
        return list.OrderByDescending(i => i.Temperatur).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    static Info SearchMin(List<Info> list)
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Tomt Lista");
        }
         return list.OrderBy(i => i.Temperatur).FirstOrDefault();;
    }
```

Comment: An alternative is to use First() and skip the check for zero length but that is more a matter of taste.

Comment: @JohanLarsson If you skip the check for zero length then if the data source contains no items, an `InvalidOperationException` will be thrown, `Sequence Contains no elements`.

Comment: @Alex Yes but we throw the same exception in our check

Comment: @Alex Exactly, so it comes down to whether returning an exception with a different error message and one less level on its stack trace is worth the extra code.

Comment: Ah okay. I was excepting an `InvalidArgumentException` which is a better choice in my opinion. Personally, I would use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault` in this context too.